# Android CalendarView displaying Icons or Text on Cell

Tags: android, calendar, calendarview

I've been trying, with no success, even with google searching on the web and whatnot, to use the Android CalendarView and display on its visual cells icons or even text that represent events that my application wants to display to the user.

So, my question is : Has anyone been able to do this using the Android CalendarView present on the Android SDK?

Comment: https://medium.com/@Patel_Prashant_/android-custom-calendar-with-events-fa48dfca8257 you can take a look into this one. It uses material design and is very simple to implement. But not Calendar View.

Comment: @ShivamSompura ... this was asked 10 yeas ago almost... but thanks

Comment: Uh-Oh! sorry I missed it.